# How to connect Microsoft Access database from Go project?

Tags: go, ms-access

I'm developing a local project for a private company and should use MS Access with golang but I did not find any information to connect to MS Access database from Go program.

I found the [`github.com/bennof/accessDBwE`](https://github.com/bennof/accessDBwE) library but I can't get it to work. Is there anybody who knows something about that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved problem with the [`github.com/mattn/go-adodb`](https://github.com/mattn/go-adodb) library. Now I'm able to connect and execute SQL queries to MS Access database.